# Back and forth between QML Canvas and C++

Tags: c++, qt, canvas, qml

I am trying to implement a 'bucket fill' tool for a QML Canvas, using a flood fill algorithm. My [initial implementation in pure QML/Javascript](https://github.com/skadge/creativ-paint/blob/084176794072888f924d44ba0ff829d7670cad21/DrawingArea.qml#L151) works well but is (expectedly) slow, and essentially unusable on mobile devices.

I would like instead to implement it in C++. Unfortunately, sharing the QML canvas content with C++ is not simple/not supported/not documented.

My current approach is convoluted, and certainly not efficient: I first serialize the canvas content using `canvas.dataToUrl("image/bmp")`, I pass the base64 encoded image to a C++ QML plugin that performs the fill:

```
void FloodFill::setImageData(const QString &data)
{
    QByteArray base64Data = data.mid(22).toUtf8();

    QImage image;
    image.loadFromData(QByteArray::fromBase64(base64Data), "BMP");

    fill(image);

    emit onCanvasFilled();
}
```

Then, at the next QML canvas repaint, I access the C++ `QImage` by re-encoding it in base64 on the C++ side, and then using the base64 string as an image source in QML.

**In summary:** canvas -> base64 encoding via `toUrlData` -> C++ -> decode into `QImage` -> flood fill -> re-encode into base64 string -> decode as QML image -> paint the QML image over the canvas.

This is clearly highly inefficient.

Ideally, I would like to access the memory address of the canvas' [`CanvasImageData`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvasimagedata.html) from C++ to edit directly the pixels, without any copy.

The next best option would be to copy both ways a `CanvasImageData` (but the C++ type for `CanvasImageData` is unfortunately private).

Any other suggestions?

(I want to add that I've looked as well at the `QImageProvider` interface, but I do not see how I can make it work in this situation, as the image provider would have to be instanciated inside my QML plugin, and I do not see how I could then register the image provider with the QML engine).

Comment: You should implement your custom class derived from either QQuickItem or QQuickPaintedItem instead

Comment: Thanks @folibis, that's indeed the best option.

Answer (score 0):

@folibis suggestion of using a `QQuickPaintedItem` is the path I eventually took, and effectively solve my problem -- it is however unfortunate to have to essentially abandon the QML canvas object along the way.

Comment: Any hint or pointer to sources or materials on how to do that?